# $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n= 1$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}= 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_{n})_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ be a positive sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_{n}\longrightarrow 1$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$. Does $\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}\longrightarrow 1$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$? If so, prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge2$:

$$\left\lvert \sqrt[n]{a_n}-1 \right\rvert=\frac{\left\lvert a_n-1\right\rvert}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sqrt[n]{a_n^{k}}}= \frac{\left\lvert a_n-1\right\rvert}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt[n]{a_n^{k}}}\le\frac{\left\lvert a_n-1\right\rvert}{1}\to 0$$

And now squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=(a_n)^\frac{1}{n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log a_n}$$

$a_{n}\longrightarrow 1$, so $\log(a_{n})\longrightarrow 0$ (because $\log$ is continuous) and $\frac{1}{n}\longrightarrow 0$, so $\frac{1}{n}\log a_n \longrightarrow 0$.
Finally $\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log a_n}\longrightarrow e^0=1$ (because $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous).

Note I used two times the fact that if $u_n \longrightarrow l$ and $f$ is a function continuous in $l$ then $f(u_n)\longrightarrow f(l).$

Comment: Why not just say $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is continuous?

Comment: It is not necessarely a well known fact

Comment: @user46944 Looking at the proof, I'd say because it's not always the same $n$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I totally missed that.  Good observation.